# Extracting Dune data as a Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

does anyone know how can I extract the below data into a DF? I understand the page uses Javascript to load the data, and there's one similar answer, but I am unable to locate the "execution ID" mentioned in it.

Dune link that I want:
https://dune.com/queries/1431599/2427930

Previous "similar" post:
[Web Scraping Table from 'Dune.com' with Python3 and bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921129/web-scraping-table-from-dune-com-with-python3-and-bs4/76234626#76234626)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to see what the API request your web browser is making. In Firefox press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` to open the web developer console. Click the "network" tab, then refresh the page. Filter just for `xhr` and you will see the data fetched by your browser. Specifically you want the `POST` request that was aimed at `app-api.dune.com`.

If you click on that request, you will be able to see the request headers in the `headers` section, and the request body in the `request` section. Then you can recreate a similar request in python.